# How do I use PowerShell 2?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I work primarily on a Windows 7 machine; sometimes on a Windows 2003 R2 server or a Windows 2008 R2 server.  Its my understanding that Windows 7 and Windows 2008 both come with PowerShell 2, and maybe Windows 2003 comes with PowerShell 2.  However, when I do a Run | Powershell, the title of the window that PowerShell runs in shows it using version 1 of PowerShell.  How do I run version 2?

Comment: Which OS is that on? What does `$Host.Version` say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect what you mean is a *path* where PS is stored (that may be shown in a title). It has very little to do with actual PowerShell version. The best test is to type: $PSVersionTable.

[image: screenshot]

v1 > nothing displayed
v2, 3 and probably all future versions -> info about current version returned.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about $PSVersionTable.  Handy.  You're correct, when I issue that command I get version 2, which is all I have on this machine.  Thanks again!